# Tdarr: Meaning of status file fields?

Tags: video-conversion

In [Tdarr](https://www.Tdarr.io), the "Status" tab allows saving several csv files. There does not appear to be any documentation of the meanings of the fields in these files.

Can someone say what meanings are of the fields `DB`, `footprintId`, `scannerReads`, `ffProbeData`, `statSync`, and `videoStreamIndex`?

I also had trouble understanding `createdAt`, but figured out that it's the time the file was processed in unix time in milliseconds.

Comment: Either there is documentation or there is not, and either it can be found using searches or other common methods, or it cannot. Please note that asking this site to help you find help documentation is specifically off topic for the above reasons.

Comment: The purpose of the question is to ask for the meanings of the fields. I've removed the request for documentation and simply stated that there doesn't appear to be any.

Comment: Per this https://docs.tdarr.io/docs/plugins/classic-plugins/plugin-components/parameters/file TDarr uses ffProbe, ExifTool, and MediaInfo to pull metadata from the files. These values appear to be the results of those various tools. This info may help you find what they mean.

Comment: Hmmm. Interesting. This shows a JSON structure of example data for one row of a generated csv file. It includes fields `DB`, `ffProbeData`, `statSync`, and `videoStreamIndex`. From it, I can see `ffProbeData` is a JSON structure of data returned by ffProbe. It gives me no idea of the meanings of `DB`, `statSync`, or `videoStreamIndex`. It has no fields `footprintId` or `scannerReads`, so also gives me no idea of their meanings. So this has explained the meaning of `ffProbeData`, but not of any of the other fields. Also, it has many fields that are not in the csv files, so I wonder why that is.

Comment: `videoStreamIndex` may indicate where in a stream a particular segment belongs, based on searching for this value. The title comes up often in questions regarding streamed video. `statSync` comes up in relation to reading .js files, I think. Lots of connection to Node.js and another value: `Stat`.